# Why does this line tell me a float can not be used as integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this one line that my script is getting caught up on:

```
for d in range(len(r)/2)
```

I am not sure what value is what value it thinks in a float. I try casting the length of r/2 as an int but still I get this error. I am really new to Python and really lost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 3.x, the `/` division operator *always* gives a float value. To use integer division, use `//`:

```py
for d in range(len(r) // 2):
```

I suspect you tried `range(int(len(r))/2)` but that doesn't change how the division works.

Comment: Are you certain that you're actually running the code you think you're running? Or are you getting a similar error on a different line of code now?

Comment: When Python encounters a runtime error, it gets the line number information from the compiled representation and then *goes back to read the source file* to get the original text. So if you're running your code in some environment where something is caching the compiled results of your script, you may get an error that doesn't make sense because Python is showing you different code than what it actually compiled. Are you running Python directly from a command prompt or are you running it in some kind of IDE or other environment?

Comment: Ok. Stop IDLE, then reload it and try your modified code again. (I don't use IDLE, so I'm not certain of its behaviour.)

Comment: Stop IDLE. Find an environment that is not weird. Start again.